# How do I check for a word ( even counting duplicated letters ) in Python?

Tags: python

For example, I want to check for the word `hello`

if it's there print `true` if not print `false`

I want it to print true even if the string has something like `hellllllllooo` in it.

This is my code right now

```
n = input()
true = 0
s = 0

for i in range(1, len(n)+1):
    letter = n[s]
    if letter == "h":
```

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: What about `hellolll`? Should it match also or no?

Comment: Yes. As long as it has the letters next to each other. Basically hlelo isn't going to print true.

Comment: What about  `"helo"`. Would it contain `"hello"`?

Comment: no. It must be hello.

Comment: But why is `hellllllllllooo` a match but `helolololololo` isn't?

Comment: It must have two l's next to each other.

Comment: It would help if you defined exactly what you mean by a string A "contains" string B

Comment: basically as long as the letters " h " " e " " l " " l " " o " are next to each other, it's fine if the letters are duplicated. So basically "hhheelllloooo" would print true. while "hlelo" would print false. I don't know if it's possible like this so I'll make helololo true too.

Comment: Hi Anonyous Aye, I think your requirement is not clear.  Can you please give some thought and further clarify the requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
import re

text = input()
print(bool(re.search(r'h+e+ll+o+', text)))
```

Comment: Thank you but, ahhellloou prints false. Is there anyway to change it to true?

Comment: @AnonymousAye Should work now (with `match` the the match has to be at the beginning of the string).